# How to groupby and then add a value

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate

I have two tables and when I join and do group by, I am able to sum the `Hours` column but the `Unpaid_Balance` column gets aggregated multiple times. For example, **Smith** worked a total of 21 hours and his hourly rate is $30 so that comes out to $630. After calculating $630 I would like to add his `Unpaid_Balance` which is in dollars of $400 for a total $1,030 but instead, what I get is $630 + $400 + $400 + $400 or $1,830.

How is it possible to groupby and aggregate a column, in this case `Hours`, multiplied by $30, and then add the `Unpaid_Balance` **after** doing the groupby? Below is my code and I also tried `SUM((Hours*30)) + Unpaid_balance as amount_due` but that didn't work.

```
select 
workers.name,
SUM((Hours*30) + Unpaid_Balance) as amount_due
FROM Workers
LEFT JOIN hours
ON workers.id = hours.id
GROUP BY workers.name
ORDER BY workers.name;

Table 1
ID Hours
1  5  
1  5
1  8
2  10

Table 2
ID Name   Unpaid_Balance
1  Smith  400
2  Ryan   10
```

Comment: please mention which RDMS as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Unpaid_Balance` is fixed for any hour per each individual, then just add another aggregation for this column such as `MAX()` or `MIN()`

```sql
SELECT w.name, SUM(Hours * 30) + MAX(Unpaid_Balance) AS amount_due
  FROM Workers w
  LEFT JOIN hours h
    ON w.id = h.id
 GROUP BY w.name
 ORDER BY w.name;
```

Comment: Thank you for showing how to make use of the MAX function.

Answer (score 1):

You should be calculating total work hours from the `hours` table first then join the `hours` table's aggregate result with the `workers` table, that should work

```
select workers.name,(total_hours.hours * 30 + Unpaid_Balance) from workers left join 
 (select sum(hours) hours,id from hours group by id) total_hours on total_hours.id = workers.id
```

[Running example in Postgres is here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=dd332b3a9e6cbae2a9fd6dae7e08af53)

Comment: Thank you for the running example in Postgres. Very much appreciated!